# Example for Jacobson density theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semi-simple-rings

I'm reading through Lang's algebra. Lang gives the Jacobson density theorem in the following way:

> Let $R$ be a ring (with unity) and $E$ a semisimple $R$-module.
>   Let $R' = \operatorname{End}_R(E), \ R'' = \operatorname{End}_{R'}(E)$.
>
> Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in E, f \in R''$. Then there exists $r \in R$
>   such that
>   $$f(x_i) = r.x_i, i = 1, \ldots, n .$$

In other words, $f$ acts as some $r \in R$ on every finitely-generated
submodule of $E$. Of course, if $E$ is finitely generated, every element
of $R''$ acts as some element of $R$ on $E$.

In every subsequent application of the theorem, $E$ is finitely-generated over $R$.
I would like to see some standard/natural examples of situations where $E$ isn't finitely generated and not every element of $R''$ is representable as an element of $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ (though this example generalizes to any commutative ring with infinitely many maximal ideals) and
$$E=\bigoplus_p\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z},$$
where the sum is over all primes.

Then 
$$R'\cong R''\cong \prod_p\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z},$$
acting on $E$ in the obvious way.

Let $f=(f_p)\in R''$.

Any finite subset $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\subset E$ is contained in $\bigoplus_{p\in I}\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for some finite set $I$ of primes and by the Chinese Remainder Theorem there is some $r\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $f_p=r\pmod{p}$ for all $p\in I$.

However, for general $f$ there is no $r\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $f_p=r\pmod{p}$ for *all* primes $p$.